# Anything wrong with the code? printed values are not as expected

Tags: c, pointers

I have the above code but the output is not what I expected.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
}node, *nodePtr;

nodePtr* createTest()
{
    nodePtr *head = (nodePtr*)malloc(3 * sizeof(nodePtr));
    node n1 =
    {
        3
    };

    node n2 = 
    {
        4
    };

    node n3 = 
    {
        5
    };

    head[0] = &n1;
    head[1] = &n2;
    head[2] = &n3;

    return head;
}

int main()
{
    nodePtr *n = createTest();
    nodePtr n0 = (nodePtr)(n[0]);
    printf("0: %d\n", n0->a);
    n0 = n[1];
    printf("1: %d\n", n0->a);
    n0 = n[2];
    printf("2: %d\n", n0->a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be 3, 4, 5.
But I got 3, 1, and a random number. why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head[0] = &n1;
head[1] = &n2;
head[2] = &n3;
```

`n1`, `n2`, `n3` are local variables. Using their address after the function `createTest` exits is undefined behavior.

Comment: Correct. Thanks. I forget that.

Comment: Also, in this example it is ok, but in the malloc argument, pass the sizeof structure, and not the pointer.